# How do I determine the maximum voltage for a custom BLDC motor?

Tags: voltage, brushless-dc-motor, maximum-ratings

I would like to know the process that you would go through to determine the voltage rating on a BLDC. I imagine that it has something to do with how the coils are wrapped and the how many coils there are. Any further reading into this, or equations I can use would be appreciated.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. Sorry.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, Jordan, but you'll need to improve your question to prevent it being closed. How is the 3D printer relevant to the BLDC. Why do you think that designing a BLDC motor is a good place to start in hobby electronics? What research have you done on BLDC motors. Your question would be much better if you show your research and ask one specific question on a part you don't understand.

Comment: The 3d printer isn't relevant i guess, i just want to know how to get a voltage rating for a custom BLDC, I would imagine it has to do with the thickness of the coil wire, and the ammount of wraps and the ammount of coils. and the diameter of the coil.

Comment: Motors use technology with highly technical concepts. but the basics are  heat rise comes from thermal resistance*Pd and Pd = I^2R losses and other losses, while Voltage and number of pole pairs per Rev determines the RPM with no load often rated as kRPM/V.  I think you should study 1st , buy and compare specs with measured results before you try to design so you can understand what it takes to design.

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt Thank you very much, if you post this in the form of an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Motors use technology with highly technical concepts.

But the basics are heat rise comes from thermal resistance*Pd and ,
Pd = I^2R losses and other losses,
while Voltage and number of pole pairs per Rev determines the RPM,
 with no load often rated as kRPM/V.

Torque is max. with current at start with rated V at 100%  and has zero torque at no-load full speed. Max rated power is often measured around 82% no-load RPM for linear loads but depends on load, water cooling etc.

I think you should study 1st , buy and compare specs with measured results before you try to design so you can understand what it takes to design.